# Creating A File Resource Using Tomcat JNDI

Tags: java, tomcat, properties, jndi

I need to read an `application.properties` file from a servlet application using `Tomcat` container. The file can not be included in my `war` so it can't be under webapps or `Tomcat` root folder in any ways. The file has to be somewhere in the folder. I also can not use `FileInputStream` to read the properties file. Only option I have is to define a `JNDI` name for a folder / directory and look that `JNDI` properties during runtime to find the folder location to read the file. Is thee any working example out there?

Comment: The JNDI approach would require some `InputStream` as well...

Comment: You cannot use `FileInputStream` why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have chalked out a solution for myself reading the following similar posts and articles.

[The Context Container](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html)

[Reading a global variable from tomcat with JNDI. Example not working](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1158168)

[java:comp/env is not bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966688/javacomp-env-is-not-bound)

I have defined a Environment inside my Context for my web application under 
\conf\Catalina\localhost\mywebapp.xml as follows....

```
    <Environment name="propertiesfilelocation" value="E:\\tmp\\application.properties"
     type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
```

Then accessed my properties file using a JNDI lookup to get the file name.

```
   Context ctx  = new InitialContext();
   Context envCtx = (Context)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env");
   String propertiesFileLocation = (String) envCtx.lookup("propertiesfilelocation");
   LOGGER.info("String property === " + propertiesFileLocation);

   properties.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesFileLocation));
```

@home : Yes you are right it involved FileInputStream. However, I am happy with the solution because I am no longer hard coding my folder location inside my Java code which makes my app more portable.

Comment: Your question explicitly states that you cannot use `FileInputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly different approach to a similar problem. I also toyed with the idea of JNDI but I found this a bit of overkill.

I found another article by BalusC. It allows you to specify folder relative to your tomcat installation and deploy all your properties files there. So you keep configuration external to your application but you don't require seperate configuration for every properties file for every app.

Here it the link:
[Where to place and how to read configuration resource files in servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-configuration-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application)

and the preferred choice is as follows:

> Put it in the classpath, so that you can load it by
>   `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()` with a classpath-relative path:
>
> ```
> Properties properties = new Properties();
> properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename.properties"));
> ```
>
> Here `filename.properties` is supposed to be placed in one of the roots
>   which are covered by the default classpath of a webapp, e.g.
>   `webapp/WEB-INF/lib`, `webapp/WEB-INF/classes`, `appserver/lib` or `JRE/lib`.
>
> If the properties file is webapp-specific, best is to place it in
>   `WEB-INF/classes`. If you're developing a project in an IDE, you can
>   also drop it in src folder (the project's source folder).
>
> You can alternatively also put it somewhere outside the default
>   classpath and add its path to the classpath of the appserver. In for
>   example Tomcat you can configure it as `shared.loader` property of
>   `tomcat/conf/catalina.properties`.

I hope this helps.

Allan

Comment: Look up what 'infamous' means, and don't make offensive comments here.